# What action/hook do I need to register to have my plugin handle front-end editing?

Tags: plugins, actions, front-end

What action/hook do I need to register to have my plugin handle front-end editing?

For example; with the plugin `Elementor` if a user clicks the below blue button they get taken to the url `http://website.com/?page_id=XX&elementor` and the Elementor plugin renders the front-end editor.

[image]

What action do I need to register to handle/detect a `http://website.com/?page_id=XX&MY_PLUGIN_NAME`?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_template also check out the related functions

Comment: Elementor is on Github, why not learn from what they did? If you only wanting an Elementor widget, they also have some starter plugin.  https://github.com/pojome/elementor-hello-world